# Print images on standard paper in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing

My children enjoy creating artwork in paint or paint.net, and often want to print it. But when printing an image file, Windows 7 brings up a special "Print Pictures" dialog instead of the normal print dialog, and only photo papers are selectable. I just want to print on standard printer paper. Can I somehow force Windows to let me use that? The only workaround I have found is to copy-paste into a document file type first, or print to PDF first, and then print THAT file. And that annoys me.

I guess it's relevant, so I'll mention I'm printing with an Epson WF-3620.

Comment: Depends on your printer driver. My printers allow me to select paper type irrespective of what I'm printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of profiles that the printer uses. Select the Standard profile:

- Open Paint
- Press Ctrl-p to print
- Select the printer
- Press Settings
- Press "Dokumente Standardqualität" (or the English equivalent)

The picture shows the (german) dialogs on my computer. If you have not installed the Epson driver yet I advise you to do so.

[image: Benutzereinstellungen]

Comment: Wow, thanks for responding to this question! I still hadn't figured this out 2 years later...and although your dialogs look different (in addition to being in a different language) I was able to find what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: For me, on the special "Print Pictures" dialog there is a tiny "Options" link in the bottom right. From there I can click "Printer Properties" and I get to the dialogs in your screenshot. Selecting "Document - Standard Quality" works great!